# How to forward private chat messages automatically to a specific group in Telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I want to automatically forward private messages sent by my friend to my personal chat to a private group in Telegram.

Currently, I've tried using a Telegram bot to read messages sent to the bot and forward them to a specific group. However, my specific requirement is for the Telegram bot to act as an intermediary, forwarding messages from your friend's private chat with me to a private group. This way, your friend will perceive the communication as if it's directly with you, while the bot is monitoring and forwarding the messages.

I know there is a privacy and security issues, but is there any possible way to achieve this?